# Change SQL Server settings without restarting services

Tags: sql-server

I can change SQL Server settings using Management Studio or programmatically as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266697/changing-sql-server-settings-programmatically).

I would like to make this changes WITHOUT the need to restart SQL Server services. Is there any trick to do so??

Comment: Which specific settings?

Comment: I need to change Server authentication setting programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the Authentication Mode, you can do this by running the following SQL

```
USE master
DECLARE @INSTANCEID VARCHAR(30), @STRVERSION VARCHAR(30), @SQLVERSION VARCHAR(30), @CMD VARCHAR(2000)
SET @SQLVERSION = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))))
SET @INSTANCEID = ((SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS VARCHAR)))

IF (SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@SQLVERSION,2),'.','')) = 10 
    SET @STRVERSION = 'MSSQL10'
ELSE
 IF (SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@SQLVERSION,2),'.','')) = 9
  SET @STRVERSION = 'MSSQL'

IF @INSTANCEID IS NULL AND @STRVERSION = 'MSSQL'
 SET @INSTANCEID = 1
ELSE
 IF @INSTANCEID IS NULL AND @STRVERSION = 'MSSQL10'
  SET @INSTANCEID = 'MSSQLSERVER'

SET @CMD = 'xp_regwrite ' + 'N' + '''HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE''' + ',' + ' N' + '''Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\'+ @STRVERSION +'.'+ @INSTANCEID + '\MSSQLServer'''+','+' N'+'''LoginMode'''+', '+'REG_DWORD'+','+ ' 2' --2 is mixed auth.

EXEC(@CMD)
--PRINT @CMD
```

You may also have to ensure that the `sa` login is enabled.

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

**You will however still have to restart the SQL Server service.**

Comment: Restarting is the main problem. But thank you :)

Comment: Well, then the answer is simple: "No, you cannot change this setting without restarting."

Comment: You could just use xp_instance_regwrite as per my answer to make it a lot more robust

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what settings you changed based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189631.aspx. Some require a restart (RR), other can be done via [RECONFIGURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176069.aspx)

There is no trick or workaround. At all.

Edit, now we know it is Authentication mode...

This is automatically deals with the instance name

```
 EXEC xp_instance_regwrite 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', 
    N'LoginMode', 
    REG_DWORD, 
    1; -- or 2 for mixed
```

Restart is still needed